# How to detect out of idle state in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I use GetLastInputInfo() to understand if the user is afk. I run it one in a few minutes.

Is there a effective way to catch out of idle state (window of the application could be rolled up)?

I dont like using GetLastInputInfo() for this as I have to spam checking it every few seconds. And I dont like to check raw WM_INPUT as some devices could be not registered (some gamepads, usb mouse maybe and so on).

What is the best way to resolve this?

Comment: There is no out-of-idle notification.  Best you can do is monitor the mouse/keyboard activity yourself using `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `RegisterRawInputDevices()`. Raw Input should be able to handle everything.

Comment: The best way is to leave it up to the operating system.  The odds that your program owns the foreground and can *actually* determine that the user fell asleep are just not very good.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx